# Check if cell exists in different sheet and return a value if true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a long list of names in a sheet that need to be sorted into 3 different groups (1, 2 & 3). Every name appears once in one of 3 existing spreadsheets. What I'm trying to do is to get excel to check if the name exists in sheet 1, 2 or 3 and depending on that return the correct group number to the last sheet.

[Logically the table would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuP9r.png)

So far I've tried to use this formula but it's throwing an error because apparently the syntax is wrong. I don't know what the issue is tho:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('OptIns Group1'!D2:D35016, [@Msisdn])>=1,"1",IF(COUNTIF(OptIns Group2'!D2:D11295, [@Msisdn])>=1,"2","3"))
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT()` seems like a good candidate. You could put that formula on your last sheet and compare each name to each list of names on each sheet. Multiply the result * 1, 2, or 3 which represent the source sheets then add the results inside the function.

Comment: Looks like you were missing a single quote: `=IF(COUNTIF('OptIns Group1'!D2:D35016, [@Msisdn])>=1,"1",IF(COUNTIF(‘OptIns Group2'!D2:D11295, [@Msisdn])>=1,"2","3"))`

Comment: I found a solution:

`=WENN(ISTFEHLER(SVERWEIS($A102;Optins1!$D$2:$D$51;1;FALSCH));WENN(ISTFEHLER(SVERWEIS($A102;Optins2!$D$2:$D$51;1;FALSCH));WENN(ISTFEHLER(SVERWEIS($A102;Optins3!$D$2:$D$51;1;FALSCH));"";3);2);1)`